# Como corrigir esse erro em java?

Tags: java, api

estou tentando criar uma Api com Spring Boot.

No entanto, mesmo eu fazendo a implementação de todas as dependências no arquivo pom.xml, o erro persiste.

A mensagem de erro é:

> Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:compile (default-compile) on project demo: Fatal error compiling: invalid target release: 11 -> [Help 1]

Comment: Qual é a versão da sua JVM 1.7 ou 1.8? Desconfio que você esteja usando a 1.7, instale a 1.8 e aponte o JAVA_HOME para esta nova instalação.

Answer (score 0):

Força o maven baixar essa dependência. Vai no projeto, clica com botão direito e depois maven - >update.
Depois usar maven clean e maven install